# SharePoint2013 with Linkedin

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I  have requirement to get a updates from Linkedin Account and display it in a Sharpoint 2013.

Is there any method is there to retrive the updates from linkedin?or How to integrate the linkedin to SharePoint 2013?

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Comment: did you find a solution in the meantime? could you please post it as an answer, as it is also interesting for other people (e. g. me!) :-)

Answer (score -1):

you can use linkedin plugin with script editor webpart :

http://sp2013.blogspot.fr/2012/09/sharepoint-2013-and-linkedin.html

Comment: Can you post the relevant info from the link in your answer in case in the future the post is (re)moved.